# Pandas read SQL with multiple parameters including list

Tags: python, pandas

I found many similar questions on the stackoverflow, but none of the solutions worked for me. I tried to do it in different ways, but, apparently, "the devil is in the details" and I do not take into account something.

Given:
list of values (x,x1,x3....xn) and date in the format of starting and ending date[yyyymmdd, yyyymmdd] - these are parameters in my SQL query which I want to read in python.

First, I define placeholders for my list to use in query:

```
placeholders = ', '.join('?' * len(my_list))
```

Then, I define query and read it to save result in the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

query="""SELECT * FROM "my_table"
     WHERE 
     ID in ({})
     and date between ? and ?                          
     """.format(placeholders)

df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn, params=(*my_list, date))
```

This returns the error, saying (my_list contains 360 members):

***'The SQL contains 362 parameter markers, but 361 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')***

It seems that query doesn't read parameters as I want. But I do not know what is wrong with it.
Anybody can help?

- I've already tried in a different way. If I put parameters "date" first, the errror is: The SQL contains 362 parameter markers, but 2 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

How parameters should be presented in the query to be read correctly?

Comment: why don't you print out the  SQL query and run it directly?

Comment: It looks like your query has two date parameters for the between, and 360 parameters in my_list. You need to pass a start date and end date.

Comment: @anon01, you mean like this: df=pd.read_sql_query("""SELECT * FROM "my_table"
         WHERE 
         ID in ({})
         and date between ? and ?                          
        """.format(placeholders),  conn,  params=(*my_list, date))

Comment: @Col Bates - collynomial, yes right - query has 362 parameters: 360 - in list and 2 - date with starting and ending dates like this: [yyyymmdd, yyyymmdd]. I didn't show it in the code here but I define it